# UIScrollview not displaying correctly second time around

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollview which loads fine, displays fine, does everything just fine. I then push another view controller, call it VC2, which also works fine. From VC2 I pop to go back to the UIScrollview and here is the weird behavior... when the UIScrollview comes back, the first (I am guessing) 300 pixels from the top are cut off. I can still see the content if I pull the page down but obviously that's not working for me. Anyone have any thoughts?

Here is the code:

This is creating the ScrollView:

```
-(IBAction)startNewSearch:(id)sender
{
NewSearch *VCscrollView = [[NewSearch alloc] init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:VCscrollView animated:YES];
}
```

The ScrollView

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 890);
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO];
[scrollView flashScrollIndicators];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 890);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

IBAction which calls VC2 from within the ScrollView:

```
-(IBAction)previewSearch:(id)sender
{   
VCcontactServer *VC2 = [[VCcontactServer alloc] init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:VC2 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Try to check scrollView's autoresizingMask

Comment: I tried using scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone; and tried using scrollView.autoresizingMask =(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight); but same result. BTW, I used these commands in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: Quick and not good solution is set frame for your scrollView inside viewWillAppear, but you have to figure out, why your scrollView resizes. May be your scrollView's superview not properly resizes?
Better if you post code, where you create scrollView, where you add it to subview and your loadView, viewDidLoad and if you have viewDidAppear/Disappear, then too

Comment: Andrey, your quick worked. I am still at a loss on why I am having this problem. It's all pretty standard code with no real modifications or additions up to this point. If you do a proper response to my question I will gladly check you with the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Do you add your scrollView to self.view? Is it in Interface Builder? If yes, try to create ScrollView manually in loadView and if your problem will disappear, then you should change some properties in xib. Otherwise you do something somewhere else and we need more your code, where you have deal with scrollView and it's superview.

Comment: Sorry if I was being unclear before. My ScrollView is actually a separate View Controller and not an add to subview. I call it by using the pushViewController command and have 890 pixel height xib file with various items. There is no custom init, the viewDidLoad I already posted, the standard didReceiveMemoryWarning and the viewWillAppear you suggested. That's it for the ScrollView. I will post the code on how I call the ScrollView.

Comment: can we talk in chat "iphone-ipad"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19793/discussion-between-sangony-and-andrey-soloviev)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit for the correct answer goes to Andrey Soloviev but unfortunately he did not post for me to give him credit. Adding the code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 890);
}
```

fixed the problem as described. The root of the problem ended up being a little more complex and outside of the scope of my question.